# open "https://maps.app.goo.gl" links in uber

Tags: geolocation, maps, uber

Whenever someone sends me a shared Google Maps link, I can only open it using the Google Maps app or website; I can't choose another app like Uber. Can I change that?

Comment: As far as I know the URLs an app is registered to is hard-coded in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` and since Android 12 such links have to be "verified", which means Google would have to provide information on `maps.app.goo.gl` that Ueber app is allowed to open such links: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks

Comment: Is there anything I can do as a regular user to modify this?

Comment: Users seem to be able to override the "verified link" feature in the App's info settings dialog, but this still means the app has to declare the URL in it's manifest. But there are "helper-apps" that allow more flexibility, see the discussion on https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246819/2241